# Optimizing a Cross Join in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is it possible to optimize Cross Joins in Spark SQL ? The requirement is to populate a column `band_id` based on age-ranges defined in another table. So far I have been able to implement the same thru a `Cross Join` and `WHERE` clause. But, I was hoping if there is a **better** way to code this and alleviate performance issues. Can I use a broadcast hint ? (sql provided below)

Customer: (10 M records)

```
id | name | age
X1 | John | 22
V2 | Mark | 29
F4 | Peter| 42
```

Age_band table: (10 records)

```
band_id | low_age | high_age
B123    |  10     | 19
X745    |  20     | 29
P134    |  30     | 39
Q245    |  40     | 50
```

Expected Output:

```
id | name | age | band_id
X1 | John | 22  | X745
V2 | Mark | 29  | X745
F4 | Peter| 42  | Q245
```

Query:

```
select
from cust a
cross join age_band b
where a.age between b.low_age and b.high_age;
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

From [`SparkStrategies.scala`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.0.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/SparkStrategies.scala#L126) source, it seems like in your case you can but you don't have to specify either `cross` or `broadcast` hint, because Broadcast Nested Loop Join is what Spark will select regardless:

```
   * ...
   * - Broadcast nested loop join (BNLJ):
   *     Supports both equi-joins and non-equi-joins.
   *     Supports all the join types, but the implementation is optimized for:
   *       1) broadcasting the left side in a right outer join;
   *       2) broadcasting the right side in a left outer, left semi, left anti or existence join;
   *       3) broadcasting either side in an inner-like join.
   *     For other cases, we need to scan the data multiple times, which can be rather slow. 
   * ...
```

Comment: thanks. so I should only be using LEFT JOIN (instead of cross join) like : `LEFT JOIN age_band b on a.age between b.low_age and b.high_age` ?

Comment: Also, when to use `Cross Join` instead of `Left Join` (or vice-versa) based on inequality conditions like the one above ?

Comment: Yes, you can use `left join` if you need all customers in the result, even those with no assigned band, otherwise just a `join` will suffice. In earlier Spark versions (prior to 3.0) you would use explicit `cross` designation because `spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled` was set to `false` by default, and Spark would try to protect you from executing a query "by mistake" (what it thought was a mistake :)).

Comment: thanks again...final question - is there any scenario where one would use `cross join` specifically ? Is there any impact to performance between using `cross join` explicitly instead of a `left join` based on inequality conditions ?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use the `cross join` but the `left join` is enough. When I do both of them, the physical plans for query execution are slightly different. I prefer to use the later one.

```
val df3 = spark.sql("""
    SELECT 
        id, name, age, band_id
    FROM 
        cust a
    CROSS JOIN 
        age_band b
    ON 
        age BETWEEN low_age and high_age
""")

df3.explain

== Physical Plan ==
*(3) Project [id#75, name#76, age#77, band_id#97]
+- BroadcastNestedLoopJoin BuildLeft, Cross, ((age#77 >= low_age#98) AND (age#77 <= high_age#99))
   :- BroadcastExchange IdentityBroadcastMode, [id=#157]
   :  +- *(1) Project [id#75, name#76, age#77]
   :     +- *(1) Filter isnotnull(age#77)
   :        +- FileScan csv [id#75,name#76,age#77] Batched: false, DataFilters: [isnotnull(age#77)], Format: CSV, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/test1.csv], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(age)], ReadSchema: struct<id:string,name:string,age:int>
   +- *(2) Project [band_id#97, low_age#98, high_age#99]
      +- *(2) Filter (isnotnull(low_age#98) AND isnotnull(high_age#99))
         +- FileScan csv [band_id#97,low_age#98,high_age#99] Batched: false, DataFilters: [isnotnull(low_age#98), isnotnull(high_age#99)], Format: CSV, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/test2.csv], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(low_age), IsNotNull(high_age)], ReadSchema: struct<band_id:string,low_age:int,high_age:int>


val df4 = spark.sql("""
    SELECT  /*+ BROADCAST(age_band) */ 
        id, name, age, band_id
    FROM 
        cust a
    LEFT JOIN 
        age_band b
    ON 
        age BETWEEN low_age and high_age
""")

df4.explain

== Physical Plan ==
*(2) Project [id#75, name#76, age#77, band_id#97]
+- BroadcastNestedLoopJoin BuildRight, LeftOuter, ((age#77 >= low_age#98) AND (age#77 <= high_age#99))
   :- FileScan csv [id#75,name#76,age#77] Batched: false, DataFilters: [], Format: CSV, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/test1.csv], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<id:string,name:string,age:int>
   +- BroadcastExchange IdentityBroadcastMode, [id=#192]
      +- *(1) Project [band_id#97, low_age#98, high_age#99]
         +- *(1) Filter (isnotnull(low_age#98) AND isnotnull(high_age#99))
            +- FileScan csv [band_id#97,low_age#98,high_age#99] Batched: false, DataFilters: [isnotnull(low_age#98), isnotnull(high_age#99)], Format: CSV, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/test2.csv], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(low_age), IsNotNull(high_age)], ReadSchema: struct<band_id:string,low_age:int,high_age:int>
```